# Grass7 - r.regression.multi and new raster

Tags: raster, grass-gis, statistics

I am on the learning curve with Grass7. I managed to make r.regression.multi work, but there is one thing that would be of high interest for me: it is possible to create a new raster showing the results (residuals) of the analysis in a new raster? 
This would enable me to nicely locate the areas with high residuals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sure:

```
r.regression.multi help
...
  residuals   Map to store residuals
  estimates   Map to store estimates
```

The command delivers overall statistics including AIC etc. (results are identical to R) as well as a "residuals" map. I have added this in the [manual page](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.regression.multi.html).

Comment: Got it! I had overlooked the "optional" options. Perfect, a wonderful tool.

Comment: Glad you solved it. And unlike R, r.regression.multi works fast with gigantic data sets...